# R: Use an n-dimensional array as indices to subset an n+1 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, subset

I have an (n, m, p) array of values and an (n, m) array of integers between 1 and p, and I want to use the integers as indices to select an irregular (n, m) subset of the values.

```
for(i in 1:dim(values)[1]) {  
 for(j in 1:dim(values)[2]) {  
  slice[i, j] <- values[i, j, indices[i, j]]  
 }  
}
```

Is there an intuitive, built-in way to do this in R, preferably without flattening? What if there are an arbitrary number of dimensions (n1, ..., nk, p)?

Comment: Please include sample data as well as expected output

Answer (score 0):

I tried to generalize it.

```
# example values
k <- 3    # dim=c(n1, n2, ..., nk)
n1 <- 5; n2 <- 6;  n3 <- 4; p <- 5
set.seed(1); values <- array(sample(n1*n2*n3*p), dim = c(n1, n2, n3, p))
set.seed(1); indices <- array(sample(p, n1*n2*n3, replace = T), dim = c(n1, n2, n3))

# do +1 to last dim and put indices into it (to enable apply() to get both information).
values2 <- array(values, dim=c(n1, n2, n3, p+1))
values2[,,,p+1] <- indices

   values[1,1,1,]  # [1] 160 477 111  27 569
   indices[1,1,1]  # [1] 2
   values2[1,1,1,] # [1] 160 477 111  27 569   2  # last values is index (value2[1,1,1,p+1])
   values2[1,1,1,][values2[1,1,1,p+1]]  # 477

# using apply(), get the values with all combination of n1, ..., nk
slice2 <- apply(values2, 1:k, function(x) x[x[p+1]])

   # check just to be sure
   slice <- array(NA, dim = c(n1, n2, n3))
   for(a in 1:n1) for(b in 1:n2) for(c in 1:n3) {
     slice[a, b, c] <- values[a, b, c, indices[a, b, c]] }

   identical(slice, slice2)  # [1] TRUE  # no problem
```